# What's wrong with this ReactRouter.match() implementation?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm trying to serve up React from my server via express.

The error I'm getting, though, when I hit localhost:3000 is:

```
TypeError: (0 , _reactRouter.match) is not a function
    at /Users/chris/code/affordance/app/server.js:20:3
```

Here's the server.js file that does that:

```
import path from 'path';
import { Server } from 'http';
import Express from 'express';
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import { match, RouterContext } from 'react-router';
import routes from './routes';
import NotFoundPage from './components/NotFoundPage';

// Initialize the express server, and tell it to use ejs
const app = new Express();
const server = new Server(app);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

// Tell express where the static assets are
app.use(Express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  match(
    { routes, location: req.url },
    (err, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {

      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).send(err.message);
      }

      if (redirectLocation) {
        return res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);
      }

      let markup;
      if (renderProps) {
        markup = renderToString(<RouterContext {...renderProps}/>);
      } else {
        markup = renderToString(<NotFoundPage/>);
        res.status(404);
      }

      return res.render('index', { markup });
    }
  );
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production';
server.listen(port, err => {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err);
  }
  console.info(`Server running on http://localhost:${port} [${env}]`);
});
```

So as far as I can tell, I'm importing it the way I see it used elsewhere (for instance, [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/13-server-rendering)).

I'm missing something, and I don't know what to guess or think next. What am I doing wrong?

ps - react-router is at version 4.0.0, docs for match are [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code looks correct if you used react router prior to v4, but react-router v4 has breaking changes throughout the codebase, including the method for server rendering. In v4, there is a new component specifically for server rendering - `StaticRouter`.

Your code should looks something like this with v4:

```
import path from "path";
import { Server } from "http";
import Express from "express";
import React from "react";
import { renderToString } from "react-dom/server";
import { StaticRouter } from "react-router";
import App from "./app";
import NotFoundPage from "./components/NotFoundPage";

// Initialize the express server, and tell it to use ejs
const app = new Express();
const server = new Server(app);
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));

// Tell express where the static assets are
app.use(Express.static(path.join(__dirname, "static")));

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  // This context object contains the results of the render
  const context = {};

  const html = renderToString(
    <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
      <App />
    </StaticRouter>
  );
  res.status(200).send(html);
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "production";
server.listen(port, err => {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err);
  }
  console.info(`Server running on http://localhost:${port} [${env}]`);
});
```

[Here](https://ebaytech.berlin/universal-web-apps-with-react-router-4-15002bb30ccb#.ip0ugqbut) is a really nice annotated article by EbayTech showing how to set up an app with StaticRouter(for server) and BrowserRouter(for client)

Comment: Just did this, unfortunately I'm stuck with the same error.

I'm starting it up by:

`NODE_ENV=production node_modules/.bin/babel-node --presets react,es2015 app/server.js`


Would this be affecting it because of any reason?

Comment: Ah, I'm so sorry, I will update my answer. So the match as you use it is in v2 and 3, but not in v4. The match that you link to in the documentation is used in the routes of react-router, and doesn't have to do with SSR. If you look at the package.json in your example, its using react-router v2. You are supposed to use `StaticRouter` in your server side code for v4. I will update my answer tonight when I get a chance.

Comment: Hey Yo, thank you so much. I just got around to logging all the imports, match was coming up null, and I realized that exactly the kind of thing you were talking about is what's going on and was about to go read through the source of 4.0.0.

Shoulda read the react router api docs all the way through, and more carefully. Thank you so much! Woulda taken me a bit to realize what I was actually looking for was `StaticRouter`

Comment: I updated my answer with code that uses StaticRouter, if you want to take a look.