# React Router v4 equivalent to match()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, isomorphic-javascript

I am working on a universal react project. I found quite a few helpful resources for creating such an app, but most seemed to be outdated. One in particular was perfect, but the problem is that a very important section of code was written with React-router version 3.

This is the code:

```
match({ routes, location: req.url }, (err, redirectLocation, props) => {
  if (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err.message);
  } else if (redirectLocation) {
    res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);
  } else if (props) {
    const markup = renderToString(<RoutingContext {...props} />);
    res.render('index', { markup })
  } else {
    res.sendStatus(404);
  }
});
```

When I use this with react router 4, I get the error:

```
TypeError: (0 , _reactRouter.match) is not a function
```

(keep in mind it looks this way because i'm compiling with Babel)

My question is how do I get the same functionality as the code snippet above, while using react-router 4?

Comment: V4 has some drastic changes to the code base. If you want to continue using match, you have to switch back to a lower version. See a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42821551/routing-universal-apps-nodejs-react-error-0-reactrouter-match-is-not-a) which suggests to use StaticRouter in place for server side rendering

Comment: Is it common practice in development to revert back to older versions? I figured it was best to adapt to the new changes. Would I be missing anything by reverting back?

Comment: please refer https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/matchPath might be useful

Comment: @AaronGill-Braun any luck found here, i am at the same place and seeking a similar solution fo make the app render.

Comment: @AaronGill-Braun I am facing the same situation and were you able to find the solution?