# react + SSR: TypeError: match is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am following this tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Smk2FusU_70 (Right at the 28:38 mark)

However it came out before v4 and I'm getting an error:

```
/Users/morganallen/Desktop/react_ssr/myapp/server/index.js:55
            match({routes, location: req.url}, (error, redirect, ssrData) => {
            ^

TypeError: match is not a function
    at fs.readFile (/Users/morganallen/Desktop/react_ssr/myapp/server/index.js:55:13)
    at tryToString (fs.js:455:3)
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:442:12)
```

I saw in this answer it looks like he's having a similar issue - [What's wrong with this ReactRouter.match() implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42797543/whats-wrong-with-this-reactrouter-match-implementation)

Although I'm not quite sure make the change in the `else{}` statement for `match({})`

What should I do to make it work?

```
require('import-export')
require('babel-core/register')({presets: ['es2015', 'react']})

const http = require('http')
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')
const express = require('express')
const react = require('react')
const reactRouter = require('react-router')
const reactDomServer = require('react-dom/server')


const renderToString = reactDomServer.renderToString


const match = reactRouter.match

const RouterContext = reactRouter.RouterContext

const staticFiles = [
    '/static/*',
    '/logo.svg',
    '/asset-manifest.json',
    '/favicon.ico'
]

const app = express()

app.server = http.createServer(app)

app.use(express.static('../build'))


staticFiles.forEach(file => {
    app.get(file, (req, res) => {
        const filePath = path.join(__dirname, '../build', req.url)
        res.sendFile(filePath)
    })
})

const routes = require('../src/routes').default()

app.get('*', (req, res) => {

    const error = () => res.status(404).send('404')

    const htmlFilePath = path.join(__dirname, '../build', 'index.html')

    fs.readFile(htmlFilePath, 'utf8', (err, htmlData) => {

        if(err) {
            error()
        }
        else{
            match({routes, location: req.url}, (error, redirect, ssrData) => {
                if(error){
                    error()
                }
                else if(redirect){
                    res.redirect(302, redirect.pathname + redirect.search)
                }
                else if(ssrData){
                    const ReactApp = renderToString(react.createElement(RouterContext, srrData) )
                    const RenderApp = htmlData.replace('{{SSR}}', ReactApp)
                    res.status(200).send(RenderApp)
                }
                else{
                    error()
                }
            })
        }
    })
})

app.server.listen( process.env.PORT || 8080)
console.log(app.server.address().port)
```

My package.json file

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "import-export": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "^16.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.1.1",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.17"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Comment: what version of react-router are you using?

Comment: 4.2 added my package.json file

Comment: `mount` does not exist in 4.2. seems like your tutorial is using v3.x.  You should install 3.x instead if you want the tutorial code to work.  v3 -> v4 was a large breaking change to many react-router apis.

Comment: where did I use mount? What can I do to make it work for 4.2

Comment: sorry, I meant `match` :P

Comment: ahh ok :-) Is there a replacement?

Comment: for SSR, you use a different router (`StaticRouter`).  So, the entire SSR flow  has radically changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `matchPath` for React Router 4+

As noted above, though off topic from your question... you should be using `StaticRouter` for React Router 4

```
app.get("*", ( request, response ) => {
const store = configureStore();

const promises = routes.reduce((acc, route) => {
    if (matchPath(request.url, route) && route.component && route.component.initialAction) {
        acc.push(Promise.resolve(store.dispatch(route.component.initialAction())));
    }
    return acc;
}, []);

Promise.all(promises)
    .then( () => {
        const context={};
        const markup = renderToString(
          <Provider store={store}>
              <StaticRouter location={request.url} context={context}>
                  <App />
              </StaticRouter>
          </Provider>
        );

        const initialData = {};

        response.send(`
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html class="no-js" lang="en">
                <head>
                </head>
                <body>  
                    <div id="root">${markup}</div>
                    <script src="/app.bundle.js" defer></script>
                    <script>window.__initialData__ = ${serialize(initialData)}</script>
                </body>
            </html>`);

    });
});
```

I use this to call the initialAction method (which is static) on any components where I might want to preload the data for the component on the server side. However you can write all of your components without this method and the code below will work just the same.

Note that the routes is an object in another file e.g.

```
import Home from "./components/Home";

const routes = [
    {
        path: "/",
        exact: true,
        component: Home
    }
];

export default routes;
```

Comment: can you give me a code example of how that would work with matchPath?

Comment: Sure give me a few minutes to get back to my desk. I’ll amend this answer with an example and then comment again when it’s done. If it helps, please mark the answer as accepted :)

Comment: thanks, trying it now. How do you import `StaticRoute`? `const reactRouter = require('react-router'), StaticRoute = reactRoute.StaticRoute`?

Comment: `import { StaticRouter, matchPath } from "react-router-dom";`

Comment: sorry, yea, im a bit confused by this :-( not sure how to make it work with the rest of the code. https://github.com/RubikCubes/reactSSR

Comment: this is an excellent resource

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tsEHfL-Ul1Y

Comment: Yes, sorry. import is an ES6 keyword, you're using ES5 syntax for your server. You can replace with var StaticRouter = require('react-router-dom/StaticRouter');

Comment: Mark the answer as accepted if this will get you to a solution my friend :)